# mongodump can't connect, how can I dump my mongodb dump without using mongodump

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mongodump, openbsd

I have mongo 3.2.13 installed on OpenBSD 6.4.  Mongo is installed via packages (`pkg_add mongodb`).  The installation doesn't include mongodump, so I have to install it via the [mongo-tools repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools)

mongodump can't detect any servers:

```
./bin/mongodump --verbose --port=27017 --host=127.0.0.1
2019-01-04T00:57:11.552-0800    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

but mongod is running and I can connect:

```
mongo --verbose --port=27017 --host=127.0.0.1
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.13
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2019-01-04T01:02:58.148-0800 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
2019-01-04T01:02:58.149-0800 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2019-01-04T01:02:58.149-0800 D NETWORK  [thread1] connected connection!
```

I'm really only interested in one database which has about 25 collections.  What series of commands could I use to back up this database (even if the commands have to be glued together with bash, node, ruby, etc)?

### Edit: add mongo and mongdump version

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.13

./bin/mongodump --version
mongodump version: built-without-version-string
git version: built-without-git-spec
Go version: go1.11
   os: openbsd
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc

git log|head
commit 0c07b518aacdca382fc931a7946811cf16e46a78
Author: Ted Tuckman <ted.tuckman@mongodb.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 20 16:19:20 2018 -0500

    TOOLS-2109 Upgrade to go 1.11 in build script

commit 6dda8ce1473bfced00c4eff190918f29874d24bd
Author: Ted Tuckman <ted.tuckman@mongodb.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 12 10:11:06 2018 -0500
```

Currently mongodump is built from origin/HEAD.  I'll try checking out the 3.2 branch and rebuilding

Comment: I have no clue what the problem might be, it doesnt make sense to me. Please additionally provide output of `mongo --version` and `mongodump --version`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany updated to add version info

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks for your comments.  It lead me in the right direction.  I checked out the 3.2 branch of mongo-tools, rebuilt mongodump, and everything worked!

Comment: Nice! Only an API / version mismatch like this can cause such strange behaviour :D Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have compiled a compatible version of `mongodump`, see

```
mongodump --version

mongo --version
```